# Prevent jqGrid from entering edit cell using beforeCellEdit event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

Is it possible to somehow stop the cell from entering edit mode, when catching the event beforeCellEdit?

```
beforeEditCell: function (rowid, cellname, value, irow, icol) {
    if (cellname != 'aSpecificCol')
        return;

    var grid = $("#grid");

    if (aCondition == "something")
        grid.setColProp('aSpecificCol', { editable: false });
    else
        grid.setColProp('aSpecificCol', { editable: true });
 }
```

The event fires, but the setting of column property seems to not changing the edit mode.

Comment: Small remark: you are member on the stackoverflow since more as 3 years and you voted up some questions or answers only 55 times. You have right to vote up about 30 questions or answers **per day** (see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5213/147495)). The main goal or voting is providing tips for the searching engine which answers and questions are **helpful**. "Accepted" answers should not really solve the problem so there will be calculated in another way. So if you want *to help other users of the stackoverflow to find helpful information* you should use your voting right more.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The method `beforeEditCell` will be called in the middle of the editing process. It exist mostly to make some initialization in the new created input or select element.

If you need prevent some cells from editing in the cell editing mode I cen suggest you either to set `"not-editable-cell"` class in the cell sometimes before (for example in `cellattr` or in `loadComplete`) or use `beforeSelectRow` to return `false` for some cells. It `beforeSelectRow` return false the cell will be not editing.

```
beforeSelectRow: function (rowid, e) {
    var $td = $(e.target).closest("td"), iCol = $.jgrid.getCellIndex($td[0]);
    if (/* test some rules here */) {
        return false; // prevent selection and so the editing of the cell
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Right, you  need to find another alternative because `beforeEditCell` only provides a means to execute more code prior to editing the cell. From [`grid.celledit.js`](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/master/js/grid.celledit.js):

```
if ($.isFunction($t.p.beforeEditCell)) {
    $t.p.beforeEditCell.call($t, $t.rows[iRow].id,nm,tmp,iRow,iCol);
}
```

However, it seems that you should be able to call `restoreCell` to prevent edit mode:

> **restoreCell**
>
> iRow, iCol
>
> restores the edited content of cell with the row index iRow( do not mix with rowid) in index column iCol

For example:

```
beforeEditCell: function (rowid, cellname, value, irow, icol) {
    var grid = $("#grid");
    if (cellname != 'aSpecificCol') {
        grid.jqGrid("restoreCell", irow, icol);
        return;
    }
```

If that does not work, you can try adding this code to the `afterEditCell` event instead, which may be the more appropriate place.

Comment: A really good idea, but unfortunately it did not work, either with beforeEditCell and afterEditCell.